# Get value of an Object inside a Collection

Tags: php, laravel, object, laravel-collection

I use DataTables as Service from Yajra in my Laravel application.

I have a collection like this :

```php
Collection {#1178
    #items: array:2 [
    0 => array:7 [
      "email" => "user1@example.com"
      "id" => 6
      "emailBlacklisted" => false
      "smsBlacklisted" => false
      "modifiedAt" => "2019-02-05T17:20:17.723+01:00"
      "listIds" => array:2 [
        0 => 2
        1 => 3
      ]
      "attributes" => {#1139
        +"NAME": "Doe"
        +"FIRSTNAME": "John"
      }
    ]
    1 => array:7 [
      "email" => "user2@example.com"
      "id" => 1
      "emailBlacklisted" => false
      "smsBlacklisted" => false
      "modifiedAt" => "2019-02-05T21:12:04.094+01:00"
      "listIds" => array:1 [
        0 => 2
      ]
      "attributes" => {#1143}
    ]
  ]
}
```

In my blade view I show email value with {{ $email }} -> Simple

I think this is a very easy problem for you ...

But I can't display the value of attributes key. (I want to show the NAME : Doe).
-> attributes is an object inside my collection.

Thank you for helping me unlock...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to be able to display the key and the value of the attributes.

If you are utilizing blade, you could try an expanded foreach loop:

```
@foreach($attributes as $key => $value)
    {{ $key }}: {{ $value }}
@endforeach
```

This assumes that you already have access to the attributes on each individual model, such as `$item->email` or in this case `$item->attributes`. If you need to, you can do `@foreach($item->attributes as $key => $value)` to start it off.

---

If you are only looking to display a specific value, use the null-coalesce operator `??`.

```
$item->attributes['NAME'] ?? ''
```

You could use this in your logic elsewhere with any expression that might be null:

```
// the fallback does not have to be a string
$person = Person::find($id) ?? Person::first();

// it can be chained
$value = $parameter ?? $localDefault ?? $globalDefault;
```

If the NAME is not found, it will fall back to what comes after the `??`, which is an empty string in the example above. This is a nice trick to avoid any errors if the attribute doesn't exist. It is doing the same thing as a ternary checking if it is null:

```
($item->attributes['NAME'] !== null) ? $item->attributes['NAME'] : '';
```

That is obviously messy, so the null-coalesce operator comes in handy!

Comment: Ok thank you, but with this foreach loop, all attributes showed and I want to show NAME only.
if($key == "NAME") { echo $value; } this method is enough? Or is there another way without using an if condition ?

Comment: @yagrasdemonde, see my edit regarding the null-coalesce operator. Forget the foreach loop and access it directly using the example.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so, @GoogleMac put me on the track. 
In fact, as the NAME attribute is not always present, I have to test the variable with an

```php
    isset()
```

function and not

```php
    !== NULL
```

With

```php
    {{ isset($attributes->NOM) ? $attributes->NAME : 'NC' }}
```

The code works very well.

Thank you @GoogleMac and @Davit

Answer (score -1):

You should simply do something like:

```php
@foreach($collection as $item)
  {{$item->NAME}}
@endforeach
```

Note: NAME must be a key in the attributes variable.

The attributes variable is protected, so you can't reference it directly from outside of the object.  The value will be automatically mapped if you reference it through the object that owns it.

Comment: If you see carefully you must be notice the each item is not eloquent instance and you can directly access `attributes` attribute. It is also `belongs to` relation in this case

Comment: Fair enough, but why not?  How and why are they getting cast to arrays?